# How to fix a Wait condition error?

Tags: protractor, jasmine2.0

I have a `browser.wait()` in an E2E test which is invoking a function defined in `protractor.config.js` file. When running the test, I get the following error:

**`Failed: Wait condition must be a promise-like object, function, or a Condition object`**

FYI - the function defined in **`protractor.config.js`** contains an **If-condition** which I need for two cases. When I remove the **If-condition**, the test runs fine. The function returns a: **`deferred.promise`**

What does this exactly means and how to fix it? Have been searching, but unfortunately can't anything related to it.

Function in **`protractor.config.js`**:

```
checkMail: function(user, subjectSent) {
     const deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

     var usermail;
     var mailsubject;

     var count = 0;
     mailListener.on("mail", function(mail, seqno, attributes) {
     var mailuid = attributes.uid;
     var toMailbox = '[Gmail]/All Mail';
     var i = ++count;
     user = mail.to[0].address;
     mailsubject = mail.subject;
     if (i > 2) {
         mailListener.stop();
            return;
         }
         deferred.fulfill(mail);
     });
     if ((user === usermail) && (subjectSent === mailsubject)) {
        return deferred.promise;
    }
}
```

**E2E it-function**:

```
it("It should do xxxxxxx", (done) => {
    browser.wait(browser.params.checkMail('user_email@yyyyy.com', 'Email subject'))
     .then((email) => {
        expect(email['subject']).toEqual("Email subject");
        expect(email['headers'].to).toEqual( 'user_email@yyyyy.com' );
    });
    done();
});
```

Comment: Post the code related to the problem.

Comment: @Gunderson: added.

Comment: What is `getLastEmail`? Is it the same method as `checkMail`?

Comment: @cnishina: Oh, sorry! my bad. should be checkMail... corrected